# <Word order: Still> Negative question - Why hasn't he still recovered? or Why has he not still recovered?

Tags: grammar, usage

I am wondering Still usage in Negative questions.

I know the following.

```
• Do you still work for the government?

• Is the party still on for tomorrow?

• Isn't she still seeing Jack?
```

However, what about negative questions?

> Why hasn't he still recovered?

or

> Why has he still not recovered?

Which one is correct?

.

PS: Sorry, I've been just confused with "yet". Please look at my revised question, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither; I would say

> Why has he still not recovered?

Comment: Oh sorry, just I lost my mind, and I was confused with "yet". Please see my revised question. Anyway, Any native speakers cannot say "Why hasn't he still recovered?" ???